# Changing a username

Tags: users

I have had a small number of users on my blog whiching to change thier username.

I was reading that is in stored in the DB but where is it and how do I change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the `user_login` column at the `wp_users` table. You can edit these values using any database tool (my favorite is PHPMyadmin http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php),